# PostgreSQL mapping with NHibernate

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate, mapping

I'm working with NHibernate on both SQL Server and PostgreSQL. I encounter some problems in mapping auto_increment attributes with PostgreSQL.

```
  Id(c => c.PlayerId, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
```

Mapping the `PlayerId` this way get me errors while inserting in the PostgreSQL database.
Changing the `Generators.Identity` to `Generators.Increment`, and doubling the mapping files worked fine.
But at this point changing or doubling the mapping files is not an option in my project.

Is there any explanation why the `Generators.Identity` map won't work in PostgreSQL? Thank you.

That's the error I get:

```
    could not insert: [Company.DataMigration.DataBase.Entities.Player][SQL: INSERT INTO Player (PlayerId, PlayerName, PlayerAge, DOJ, BelongsTo) VALUES (nextval ('hibernate_sequence'), ?, ?, ?, ?) returning PlayerId]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks likely to me your PostgreSQL database lacks the required sequence. You are probably not creating the schema through NHibernate, and then you have to create yourself the sequence used for generating the id. Its name should be `hibernate_sequence`, but the complete error message should tell you.

You may use the `Native` generator instead. It switches between `Identity`, `Sequence` or `HiLo` depending on what the underlying database supports.

See [generator documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator).

Beware that those generators behave quite differently from each others, which could creates issues depending on which one is chosen. To avoid such discrepancies between target databases, use an [enhanced generator](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-enhanced) instead: it will use the same behavior on most databases.

Comment: Thank you , i'll check it out

Comment: Hey , @ frédéric , usin Native keeps getting me this error could not get next sequence value , any idea?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough details to dig further. Try providing a [MCVE](/help/mcve), and provide the complete exception message (call `.ToString()` on it, or click "Copy exception details to clipboard" if debugging under Visual Studio). Some details may be still missing in case of a `SqlException` by example: inspect its `Errors` property and extract relevant messages from it. Indicate which version of NHibernate and PostegreSQL you are using. NHibernate.Test project has numerous tests working with `native` and PostgreSQL, it is known to work.

Comment: I have still made a guess at the error cause, read my edit above.

Comment: I solved it using the sequence generator      Id(c => c.PlayerId, map =>
            {
                map.Generator(Generators.Sequence,
                              gmap => gmap.Params(new { sequence = "player_playerid_seq" }));
            })